# Make a flutter Page scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, flutter-layout, dart-pub

Hey I am currently trying to make a page scrollable in flutter/dart. 
The problem I have is that the structure is different from anything that I could find online. 
It currently looks like that:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,

  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[

      Container(...),

      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      Row(...),

      Container(...),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

I want to make the Row(...) and the second Container(...) scrollable now. 
I couldn't figure it out. 
Hopefully you can help me with it!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `Row` and `Container` in a `Column`, then wrap that `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView`;

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(...),
              Container(...),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

p.s. as of Dart 2.0 you no longer need the `new` keyword in front of your `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Flutter ListView. Something like

```
ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[600],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[500],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
    ),
    Container(
      height: 50,
      color: Colors.amber[100],
      child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
    ),
  ],
)
```

For details, have a look at the following link [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)